# How to find a column by header?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

The formula below works fine. It returns the column where the value `Status` is found on the header (first line). In my sheet this formula returns the value `B`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Status",1:1,0),4),1,"")
```

The formula below also works fine. This one is used as a custom formula for conditional formatting. I wanted to replace the explicit addressing of the cell `$B1` by the formula above.

```
=AND(IFERROR(MATCH($A1,INDIRECT("HWDev!A:A"),false),0)=0,$B1="Yes")
```

I tried to combine the two formulas above, but I am not getting the expected result. I have already tried the formulas below:

```
=AND(IFERROR(MATCH($A1,INDIRECT("HWDev!A:A"),false),0)=0,"$"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Status",1:1,0),4),1,"")&"1"="Yes")
=AND(IFERROR(MATCH($A1,INDIRECT("HWDev!A:A"),false),0)=0,INDIRECT("$"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Status",1:1,0),4),1,"")&"1")="Yes")
=AND(IFERROR(MATCH($A1,INDIRECT("HWDev!A:A"),false),0)=0,INDIRECT("$"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Status",1:1,0),4),1,row()))="Yes")
```

This is a link to an example sheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EVr-1otpjrtMSZUsP-EcvDb7ysCf5zvHWSiZyUU5838/edit?usp=sharing) (see 'Status-NotWorking??' sheet)

Any idea of how can I replace `$B1` by a formula to find it?

Thank you!

Comment: In order to better understand the question, can you share an example of your sheet?

Comment: @JoseVasquez, I have just added an example sheet. Thank you!

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? regular formula or formula for conditional formatting?

Comment: for conditional formating

Comment: as I can see in your sheet, The 2nd formula will always be FALSE because you are comparing "Status" with "Yes" everytime. In addition to the information you provided, can you please explain what's the purpose of getting the column header or at least what's the final behaviour of this?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you need to highlight the row in case the color in not on the 2nd sheet and Status is Yes. And Status column could be anywhere.

Apply this to the whole sheet (`A2:F` in your case):

`=AND(ISNA(MATCH($A1, INDIRECT("HWDev!A:A"), 0)), IFNA(OFFSET($A1, 0, MATCH("Status", $1:$1, 0) - 1) = "Yes", False))`

[image]

So, the answer to your question:

> Any idea of how can I replace $B1 by a formula to find it?

For conditional formatting you could use this to replace `$B1` (where `$B$1` is "Status"):

`OFFSET($A1, 0, MATCH("Status", $1:$1, 0) - 1)`